# Python 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyscripter

I tried running the following code in Pyscripter but it keeps returning the error "'list' object is not callable". I ran the code through the Python shell and it worked perfectly fine. I'm not quite understanding why it isn't working in Pyscripter. Also, I'm using Python 2.7.

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))
```

Even creating a simple list in Pyscripter will return the same error.

```
list()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Almost certainly you've rebound the name list to a list instance:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
>>> 
>>> list = [2,3,4]
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Don't call lists `list`, or strings `str`, etc..

Answer (score 5):

You have, somewhere previously, created a list and named it `list`. This is a bad idea. The name `list` is not treated specially in Python.  When you start up the interpreter, `list` names the list type, but if you then name something else `list`, then `list` can no longer be a name for the list type, as a name can only refer to one thing at once.

Thus, when you write `list()` expecting to create a new list (i.e. instantiate the list type), Python does what it always does: it looks up the name `list`, and then tries to apply `()` (i.e. `__call__`) to whatever has that name. Since `list` now refers to *some other list*, this fails, as `'list' objects are not callable`, exactly as the error message says.

Comment: @Olli There is not nearly enough information in your comment to even determine what you have actually done, let alone diagnose why it causes an issue. Please read [ask], and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Words **list** and **str** are keywords in Python. That's why there is an error with the script. You can try something like:

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2)))

List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(list(itertools.permutations(List, 2)))
```

Cheers!!